# Data from 2 pages as one item

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am crawling a site with products the currency that product's price is shown is it set via the url `/en-GB/` for GBP and `/en-AU/` for AUD my client wants both prices in one item.

I would like to be able to use pipelines to put it into their DB so combining it afterwards is not viable. Is their anyway with scrapy to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['price_GBP'] = response.xpath("//foo/bar").extract_first()
    request = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/en-AU/",
                             callback=self.parse_page2)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['price_AUD'] = response.xpath("//foo/bar").extract_first()
    yield item
```